# After installing Ubuntu 20.04 and accessing it, I cannot switch back to Windows 10 (Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, windows-10

I am a complete noob when it comes to this so please hear me out. I installed Ubuntu on my Desktop and Laptop. My laptop works great: the Grub GNU works and no problem with booting to Windows or Ubuntu. However, my desktop has been giving the most the problems because whenever I try to boot to my Windows side on the Grub GNU, it takes me back to the Grub GNU, so I am stuck on Ubuntu.

I followed peoples advice on these forums and used several treatments which were to no avail:

- sudo -H gedit /boot/grub/custom.cfg

  `menuentry "Windows (UEFI)" { search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi }`

I created this which gave me a UEFI Windows icon in Grub GNU. When I clicked it I got an error saying, `no such device /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`.

- Next, I tried the Boot Repair tool from Ubuntu. I went through the process but still nothing.

If anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it. If you need more information please let me know.

**Update:** Here is the link that was requested:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/b5WZv5pjbt/

Some additional information to understand is nvme0n1 is the SSD card that houses my Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Also, I used a tool called EasyBCD 2.4 which allowed me to have Ubuntu boot up by default from my partition since it was not showing in my MSI BIOS.

Comment: From Boot-Repair run the Summary report & post the link above in your question.

Comment: You seem to have a newer UEFI system, but both Windows & Ubuntu installed in the 35 year old BIOS/MBR configuration. Most repair instructions are now for UEFI. Since you have two drives, you want the Windows boot loader in the MBR of the internal drive and grub in the Ubuntu drive. Windows will not boot from an external drive, but you can boot Ubuntu from grub on an external drive. Best not to use EasyBCD as grub does not like to be installed to a partition as EasyBCD suggests. But you have two MBR, so can have Windows in one & grub in the other. Better to use UEFI, but now major change.